# My 3D View is not the same as my render result

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view

I'm new with blender and I don't know what's happening with my 3d model.
This is what it looks like with 3D view

[image]

When I tried to render, this is the result that comes up with

[image]

I've google some keywords but I still can't really solve my problem. I don't know what's going on with my render, I've tried to close Blender, then restart my computer several times, and even shut it down for a couple of hours but it doesn't help.

I'm totally new with 3D and Blender so I just follow some tutorials I watched in Youtube.

Comment: Opposite version of dupe

Comment: @Sazerac  thanks for replying, sorry but what is that "Opposite version of dupe" you're talking about? i've tried to google it with "Opposite version of dupe in blender" but i don't get it. sorry i'm not a native english speaker

Comment: dupe is short for duplicate. In the linked duplicate, the asker has essentially the same problem, but the opposite way around (object not appearing rather than appearing). The solution is the same, make sure that the render visibility is set the way you want it on each object.

Comment: @Sazerac OMG. yes thank you so much. I put the round object beforehand to help me model the head and forgot to delete that sphere.
thank you for your time